# Cross Entropy Issue in NN (No Hidden Layers)

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I am facing an error while calculating crossEntropy (values  not converging) while investigating if I calculate error by simply subtracting, my results are fine. i also used tensorflow cross entropy function for checking either its issue with my custom function or not.

Pl guide

```
self.error=self.crossentropy(Y,y_pred)
self.error=np.subtract(Y,y_pred)

def crossentropy(self, Y, Y_pred):
     return -(np.sum((Y * np.log(Y_pred)) + (1 - Y) * np.log(1 - Y_pred )) /len(Y)) 

bce = tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy()
 loss = bce(Y,y_pred)
```

[Simply Subtraction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1PXlB.png)

[CrossEntropy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gAioO.png)

Comment: Can you share the complete reproducible code so that we can investigate your problem. Thanks!